# Add ang get data from cache from HangFire

Tags: asp.net, caching, hangfire

I am trying to use Hangfire to update some lists in the cache (`HttpContext.Current.Cache`). I get a `NullReferenceException` because `HttpContext` is `null` when Hangfire is calling it.

Is there any way to use Hangfire for this or maybe I shall look for another framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not execute [changing context](http://hangfire.io/blog/2014/05/10/are-your-methods-ready-to-run-in-background.html) like `HttpContext` inside Hangfire because Hangfire can run jobs in different server and machine. If you want to access changing context like `HttpContext` probably you need to have at least share storage to do that and [dkempner](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/190) has proposal for this scenario but didn't happen till now.